# Relation betwen coefficients and roots of a polynomial, K.A.Stroud

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am stuck on example 3, page 4 of Advanced Engineering Mathematics.

The equation to be solved is $x^3+3x^2-6x-8=0$, The solution gives the roots as $-4, 2,-1$.
Is it possible for someone to show me how these roots were found? as the intermediate steps are not shown, in the solution for the example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 1):

$$x  (x^2+3x-6)=8$$
so $x$ is a divisor of $8$ if $x$ is integer

Answer (score 1):

The Rational Root Theorem says that if a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ is a root of the polynomial, where $(p,q)=1$, then $p\mid-8$ and $q\mid1$.

We can then test all possible values of $p =\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm8$ and $q=\pm1$, hopefully to find some roots of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ If it has $\,3\,$ integer roots $\,a,b,c\,$ then by [Vieta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) $\,abc = -8\,$ so, ignoring signs, the roots are $\color{#0a0}{1,1,8}$ or $1,2,4$ or $\color{#c00}{2,2,2}$. By Vieta the root sum $= -3$ is odd, so they cannot be $\rm\color{#c00}{all\ even}$. Nor can signs be chosen so $\color{#0a0}{1,1,8}$ sums to $-3.\,$ Only $1,2,4$ remains. Choose their signs so they sum to $-3.\,$ Finally, verify that the remaining linear coefficent $\, ab+bc+ca = -6$ is correct.